# STA thread Abort Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am initializing a thread as static thread as shown below

```
Thread GenerateKeywords;
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Initializes the Test Thread           
    Test = new Thread(TestMethod);

    //Sets the apartment state to Static
    Test.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    //Starts the GenerateKeywords Thread           
    Test.Start();
}
```

but when I am aborting this thread via this method

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if (Test != null)
         Test .Abort();
}
```

It is giving following exception :
"
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x13dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
"

How to get rid of this exception??

Comment: It is *not* an exception, just a notification from the debugger that an exception was detected.  Which is normal, Thread.Abort() injects an exception.  Do *not* fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ThreadAbort Exception should not be a problem. An unhandled ThreadAbortException is one of only two types of exception that does not cause application shutdown (the other is AppDomainUnloadException).

wrap it in a try catch and handle exception of type ThreadAbort and set `Thread.ResetAbort = true;`

Check this [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You should poll for some condition while running a thread so as to abort it.Set some boolean variable at button stop and then poll it inside thread method to abort it.